# How to allow a python script (that is called within a C# app) to access the USB port

Tags: c#, python, can-bus

Wondering if anyone has insight on the above.

I have a Python script that accesses and sends messages through a USB-to-CAN converter. The script works pretty flawlessly when run from the Windows command line.

I then tried to port calling this script from within a C# app. I can call the script fine. No problem there. When the script goes to connect to the USB-to-CAN converter, it throws an error similar to when the CAN converter is not plugged in to the USB port.

I know this is not a lot to go on, as far as code and seeing my errors. I don't know if I can effectively give enough real code context without making a gigantic post.

So just wondering if anyone has insight on a C# app giving USB access to a Python script called within the app.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you at least post some of the error message?  Right now we have nothing to go off of.